# SmoteBoost: Should SMOTE be ran individually for each iteration/tree in the boosting?

Tags: classification, sampling, class-imbalance, boosting, smote

As per the paper on [SmoteBoost](https://www3.nd.edu/~nchawla/papers/ECML03.pdf), SMOTE is ran for each iteration of the boosting, generating N samples, which are further added to the original training data and the weight distribution of the instances are modeified acccordingly. However, this would result in increase in the size of the training data, wherein, we add N sythetic examples of minority class in each iteration.

So, if we have T trees for the booster, we would have added N*T sythentic examples for the minority class for Tth tree. Should we rather remove the N sythetic examples after each iteration(completion of each tree) or run SMOTE just for the first tree in the booster.